# Recursive page assembling in Node.js with Express and Jade

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I've been working on an API in Node.js for the first time, and of course I needed a test page so I decided to whip one up in Node as well for the hell of it.

After wracking my mind to come up with a good way to load the header, body and footer files (Jade syntax files) and have them be friends and render together, I came up with a recursive solution.

```js
function assemblePage(name,markup)
{
    markup = markup || '';
    if (markup=='')
        fs.readFile('header.jade', function(err,data){assemblePage(name,markup+data)});
    else if (name != 'footer')
        fs.readFile(name+'.jade', function(err,data){assemblePage('footer',markup+data)});
    else
        fs.readFile('footer.jade', function(err,data){console.log(markup+data);__res.send(jade.render(markup+data))});
}
```

So all I have to call is:

```
assemblePage('home');
```

Is this the best way to go about things?

Comment: it's a good example of async with recursion, but the better way to go is to let Express handle it with layout and partials.  http://expressjs.com/guide.html#view-rendering

Comment: Thanks for your input! Looks like view partials is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should be using [expressjs](http://expressjs.com/)(High performance, high class web development for Node.js) to render your templates. 
It has a very sophisticated [View Rendering](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#view-rendering). I think what you need is called **[view partials](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#view-partials)**. In the [screencasts](http://expressjs.com/screencasts.html) section you can watch a screencast about [view partials](http://www.screenr.com/4AL)